# How do I update a column value using the column name as a procedure's parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that updates a particular table depending on another table. This is the SQL code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_update_total 
    @pid INT, @tid INT, @column_name VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT @column_name FROM tbl_tbl_table1 WHERE id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2) = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT total FROM tbl_tbl_table1 WHERE id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2) > 0 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE tbl_table1
            SET total -= (SELECT amount FROM tbl_tbl_table2 WHERE name = QUOTENAME(@column_name)) 
            WHERE id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2
        END
    END
END
GO
```

And to use it, I do this

```
EXECUTE proc_update_total N'1', N'1', N'Clothing';
```

Then I get this error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_update_employee_allowance, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Clothing' to data type int.

Please help!

Comment: the parameters you used for `Int` and `varchar` remains same, can you try using double quotes `""` for `"Clothing"`.

Comment: Generally, _**you don't**_, and this is considered poor practice. If you _really_ need to do it this way, you have to dynamic SQL ( `sp_executesql()`). Don't forget to wrap the column name with the `QUOTENAME()` SQL function. The reason there's not a better option is SQL commands are _compiled_, and part of that process involves checking security permissions. If the columns or tables to be used are part of the data, this compilation step won't be able to check access rights.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass the name of an identifier in a variable and use it in a plain SQL because SQLs are compiled, identifiers are part of the program and variables are just data

You either have to have a table that is pivoted so it stores the attribute as a row data:

```
Key, Value 
Name, John
Age, 26
Country, USA
```

Instead of columnar style:

```
Name,Age,Country
John,26,USA
```

In which case the "column name" is now row data

---

Or you have to have a massive IF/CASE

```
CASE @columnname 
WHEN 'Name'
  SELECT * FROM person WHERE Name = @colvalue
WHEN 'Age'
  SELECT * FROM person WHERE Age = @colvalue
WHEN 'Country'
  SELECT * FROM person WHERE Country = @colvalue
```

Avoid the "parameter equals x and other parameter = y or.." pattern because it potentially produces poor sql plans:

```
WHERE
  (@colname = 'name' and Name = @colvalue) or 
  (@colname = 'age' and age = @colvalue) or ...
```

---

Or you have dynamic sql, which is potentially a massive security risk if you don't validate/sanitize the input.

Always use QUOTENAME on your identifiers. Always use parameters for your data values:

```
sp_executesql 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  '+QUOTENAME(@columnname)+' = @val', '@val varchar', @val = @columnValue
```

---

Don't forget in not of these approaches you have the problem that you're trying to pass a column value in but columns have different data types and hence your @columnvue needs to be a datatype that can adequately express all the datatypes you work with

---

Or you can sack this idea off and do things as were intended with stored procedures - parameters that are correctly typed, statements that are compiled, no notions of hacking together SQLs dynamically or passing variables indicating which column to use - it would be more performant and secure to do it as Ms intended

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_update_total 
    @id1 INT, @id2 INT,@column_name VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @strquery varchar(max)

    set @strquery= 'SELECT TOP 1 '+QUOTENAME(@column_name)+ ' FROM tbl_tbl_table1 WHERE id1 = '+@id1+ ' AND id2 = '+@id2

    create table #result(data int)

    insert into #result
    exec(@strquery)


    IF ((SELECT data FROM #result) = 0)

        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT total FROM tbl_tbl_table1 WHERE id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2) > 0 
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE tbl_table1
                    SET total -= (SELECT amount FROM tbl_tbl_table2 WHERE name = QUOTENAME(@column_name)) 
                    WHERE  id1 = @id1 AND id2 = @id2
                END
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: Don't make answers that recommend SQL Injection attack vectors

Comment: @CaiusJard Can you explain how is it vulnerable to SQL injection? I have used QUOTENAME(@column_name).

Comment: where is `@id1` and `@id2` comes from ?

Comment: @Squirrel Its coming from stored procedure parameters.

Comment: You've concatenated values ?id1 and ?id2 in without knowing what they contain. Even if you knew they were ints, for example, you've still recommended concatenating values in rather than advice that is resilient to SQL Injection and the very next thing someone will do is copy your code, change ?id1 to ?userNameFromUrl and bam... Avoid leaving that door open when the facilities for parameterizing  exist; [people frequently blindly copy paste off stackoverflow](https://www.theverge.com/platform/amp/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow)